# Use static and public in static file in angular4

Tags: angular

i encountered wired situation that I import the my config.ts but my controller can't found my method.

**config.ts**

```
export class Config {
  static testforStatic = `show static`;
  public testforpublic = `show public`;
}
```

**mycomponent.component.ts**

```
import {Config} from 'config';
private configwhennew: Config = new Config();
ngOnInit() {
  console.log(`${Config.testforStatic} `);
  console.log(`${configwhennew.testforpublic} `);
}
```

Before I new this class, it only got static but couldn't return public variable.

Therefore , after `new` , it works that static didn't work.someone could explain what happened?

Answer (score 0):

A better implementation to avoid all of this mess is to change your class to a const.

This would make your config change as follows:

```
export const Config {
  testforStatic: `show static`,
  testforpublic: `show public`
}
```

Then simply import Config as you did, and reference the properties with `Config.testForStatic` and `Config.testforpublic`.

---

It might be worthwhile to checkout the Angular standard for environment variables. Here's a great read - https://medium.com/beautiful-angular/angular-2-and-environment-variables-59c57ba643be

Comment: umm..it's not in my meaning for how to implement. I want to know the class implement life cycle